# jQuery and firebase is there a better way to handle nested event?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Requirement: When i click a button, I want to check something in firebase, and then base on the result I will write to firebase different data.

Dilemma: I find myself having to nest one event inside another, basically the same dilemma with call-back hell.

Any suggestions on how i can handle nested event with jQuery and firebase better?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit-name").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let userName = $("#user-name").val().trim();
    if (userName.length > 0){
      playersRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
        console.log("snapshot is>>>", snapshot.val());
        if (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().length <=1 || !snapshot.val()){
          let index = _.get(snapshot.val(), 'length' ,0);
          let con=playersRef.child(index).push({
            name:userName
          })
          if (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().length ===1){
            gameStatusRef.set({
              0: {win:0, lose: 0, tie:0},
              1: {win:0, lose: 0, tie:0}
            });
          }
          con.onDisconnect().remove();
        }
      })

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to attach your code.

Comment: updated to include the code. thx.